# One Signal for Xamarin - how use with Android X?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, nuget, onesignal

I using [OneSignal](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Com.OneSignal/) in my Xamarin Forms app. I have problem with android. I use some package I use several packages that need Android X. This is:

-[BarcodeScanner.XF](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BarcodeScanner.XF/)

-[Xam.Plugins.Android.ExoPlayer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugins.Android.ExoPlayer/2.11.8?_src=template)

But OneSignal using CompileSdkVersion - Android 9(Api Level 28). When I try install OneSignal in android project(for Android 10) than I get this error:

```
 BarcodeScanner.XF 4.8.0 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (>= 28.0.0.3) 
 Com.OneSignal 3.10.1 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs 26.0.2 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat 
(= 26.0.2).
```

So for the single packages I need Android X for the other ones - Android 9(CompileSdkVersion). How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find a similar question in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/troubleshooting) and there is solution there.

> The problem is mismatched dependencies for the two NuGets. This can be
> resolved by manually adding a specific version of the dependency (in
> this case Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat) that can support both.

Refer to this [blog post](https://redth.codes/how-to-fix-the-dreaded-version-conflict-nuget-error-in-your-xamarin-android-projects/) for more information and a video on how to resolve the issue.